# Necessary and sufficient condition for the existence of a separation $f$ of $A$, $B$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Suppose $A,B \subset R^{n}$. Find necessary and sufficient conditions for there to be a continuous function $f$ on $R^{n}$ with $f|_{A} = 1$ and $f|_{B} = 0$. The hint is to consider $g(x) = dist(x, A)$ and $h(x) = dist(x, B)$.

I haven't been able to find very much at all from this Real Analysis textbook online, so I've come here. I really want to understand this but my textbook is very condensed and doesn't explain very much.

I think $f|_{A} = 1$ and $f|_{B} = 0$ are saying that $f$ evaluated at all points in $A$ is equal to $1$ and $f$ evaluated at all points in $B$ is equal to $0$.

The hint suggests I consider the distance function, so I think that every time $f$ is evaluated it must be on the boundary of $B$ or inside $B$. I also think this means that $A$ must be completely contained in $B$ since when $f$ is evaluated on $B$ the, distance from $A$ is $1$. Or perhaps that means that both sets are just boundary curves? I'm having a hard time thinking about this problem and an even harder time thinking about it rigorously since the author of my textbook doesn't explain all the properties that he uses in his questions.

Comment: $A$ cannot be contained in $B$, or $f(x)$ would be both $0$ and $1$ at $A\subset B$. The same argument impies that if such a function exist, then $A \cap B = \emptyset$. still this is not sufficient.

Comment: $A$ and $B$ can be totally disjoint. In fact, they have to be!, if $f$ is to be $1$ on $A$ and $0$ on $B$. But they can't be too... close: suppose $n = 1$, $A = $ rationals, $B = $ irrationals; then there is no such continuous $f$.

Comment: I can see now that $A \cap B = \emptyset$, and I can see that they can't be too close, but I'm confused about how to guarantee that $f|_{A}$ = 1 let alone $f|_{B}$ = 0

Answer (score 3):

A necessary and sufficient condition is that $\overline A \cap \overline B= \emptyset$. To see that it is necessary, assume that $x\in \overline A \cap \overline B$. Then there is $\{a_n\}$ in $A$, $\{b_n\}$ in $B$ so that $a_n \to x$, $b_n \to x$. As $f$ is continuous,

$$1 = \lim_{n\to \infty} f(a_n) = f(x) = \lim_{n\to \infty} f(b_n) = 0$$

and that's impossible. Thus such an $f$ does not exist. To show that it's sufficient, assume that $\overline A \cap \overline B = \emptyset$. As suggested, consider $f_A(x) = \text{dist}(x, A)$. Then $f_A(x)$ is zero if and only if $x \in \overline A$ (check!). Similarly, $f_B(x) = \text{dist}(x, B)$ is zero if and only if $x\in \overline B$. Let

$$f(x) = \frac{f_B(x)}{f_A(x) + f_B(x)}.$$

$f$ is well-defined as the bottom is never $0$. If $x\in A$, then $f_A(x) = 0$ and so $f(x) = 1$. If $x\in B$, then $f_B(x) = 0$ and so $f(x) =0$.